# JMH - How to measure time it takes to insert 50M items in an ArrayList

Tags: java, jmh

I've an ArrayList of 50M, I would like to measure time it takes to store that many objects in it. It seems as all JMH modes are time based, we can't really control number of executions of code under @Benchmark. For examlpe, how can I ensure the following code is run exactly 50M times per fork?

```
@Benchmark
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.SampleTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@Fork(5)
public void run(BenchmarkState state) {
    try {
        state.queue.add(System.nanoTime());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a benchmark class (`ArrayListBenchmark`) and a runner class (`BenchmarkRunner`).

- In `ArrayListBenchmark` class, you can add the benchmark method that
  iterates the desired number of times adding items to the `List`.
- In `BenchmarkRunner` class, you set the desired number of items to add to
  the `List` and config the runner options.

**Note**: Depending on your environment, adding 50M items may throw an `OutOfMemoryError`.

Benchmark class:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Benchmark;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Level;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Param;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Scope;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Setup;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.State;
import org.openjdk.jmh.infra.Blackhole;

public class ArrayListBenchmark {

    @State(Scope.Thread)
    public static class ThreadState {

        @Param({})
        private int items;

        private List<Long> list;

        @Setup(Level.Iteration)
        public void setup() {
            list = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void addItems(ThreadState state, Blackhole blackhole) {
        blackhole.consume(addItems(state.list, state.items));
    }

    private static boolean addItems(List<Long> list, int items) {
        for (int i = 0; i < items; i++) {
            list.add(System.nanoTime());
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Benchmark runner class:

```
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Mode;
import org.openjdk.jmh.results.format.ResultFormatType;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.RunnerException;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.Options;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.OptionsBuilder;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.TimeValue;

public class BenchmarkRunner {

    private static final String ITEMS = "items";

    private static final String N_50_000_000 = "50000000";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {
        runArrayListBenchmark();
    }

    public static void runArrayListBenchmark() throws RunnerException {
        Options options = new OptionsBuilder()
                .include(ArrayListBenchmark.class.getSimpleName())
                .mode(Mode.AverageTime)
                .timeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
                .warmupTime(TimeValue.seconds(1))
                .warmupBatchSize(1)
                .warmupIterations(5)
                .measurementTime(TimeValue.milliseconds(100))
                .measurementBatchSize(1)
                .measurementIterations(10)
                .param(ITEMS, N_50_000_000)
                .operationsPerInvocation(Integer.parseInt(N_50_000_000))
                .threads(1)
                .forks(5)
                .shouldFailOnError(true)
                .shouldDoGC(true)
                .resultFormat(ResultFormatType.CSV)
                .result("target/" + ArrayListBenchmark.class.getSimpleName().toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH) + ".csv")
                .build();
        new Runner(options).run();
    }
```

**Output**:

```
Result "ArrayListBenchmark.addItems":
  50.023 ±(99.9%) 0.768 ns/op [Average]
  (min, avg, max) = (48.094, 50.023, 53.020), stdev = 1.551
  CI (99.9%): [49.256, 50.791] (assumes normal distribution)

Benchmark                     (items)  Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
ArrayListBenchmark.addItems  50000000  avgt   50  50.023 ± 0.768  ns/op
```

Comment: @Obeo Instead of letting JMH execute our benchmark and keep track of number of executions, we're introducing our own loop to do that. How would JMH come up with stats like 90, 99, 99.9 percentiles whinin 50M insertions or something similar for other modes (AvgTime, Throuput)? It would think, each benchmark is one operation when infact there have been 50M operations peformed.

Comment: @Abidi Not sure I understand the issue. Is that you want '*to measure the time it takes to insert 50M items in an ArrayList*' (as the question title says). Or are you questioning the outputs you are getting? Or something else?

Comment: @Obeo appreciate your answer. With the solution you provided, we're bundling 50M executions into a single operation. This means, JMH cannot provide other metrics like avg, min and max times of those 50M executions, right? If it's not possible in JMH then all good, maybe it's a limitation of JMH or not designed for cases like mine. I'll mark the question as answered.

Comment: @Abidi If I understand correctly you should modify the mode from `Mode.SingleShotTime` to `Mode.AverageTime` in `Options`. Also, you should set the operations per invocation (50M in your case) by adding `.operationsPerInvocation(50000000)` to `Options`. I updated the answer to include these modifications and added the output.

Comment: as soon as I change mode to AvgTime, code under run() method is not executed exactly 50M times IFF I change measurementTime to let say 5 minutes. Does it mean, you're setting time to 100ms just to trigger the benchmark and because by the time run() method is completed 100ms would have elapsed so JMH won't go over 50M?

Comment: @Abidi As the output shows, the code in the answer is executed 50M times. I suggest you create a new question with your specific issue and code that reproduces it.